# obtain ADO ownership information of a file using azure devops rest apis

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to obtain ADO ownership information of a file using azure devops rest apis. But I am not sure how to do this. The scenario is that I am creating bugs using azure devops and need to obtain the file ownership information inorder to assign the created bug to the concerned person. Can you please let me know if there is a way to do this?

Comment: Hi friend, is there any update for this issue? If my answer resolved your question, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. If not, please let us know if you would like further assistance

Answer (score 0):

> obtain ADO ownership information of a file using azure devops rest
>   apis

I'm not certainly sure about the owner you mean here, any member who have corresponding permissions can modify one file in repos easily. Personal opinion, maybe you're looking for [this rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) (Get):

```
https://dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/git/repositories/{ReposName}/commits?searchCriteria.itemPath=/ConfigTrans.sln&searchCriteria.itemVersion.version=master&api-version=5.1
```

1.Replace the `{OrgName},{ProjectName},{ReposName}` with your own Organization name, Project Name and Repos name.

2.Also, you need to modify the itempath and itemversion here: `searchCriteria.itemPath=/ConfigTrans.sln&searchCriteria.itemVersion.version=master`

I used `/ConfigTrans.sln` and `master` because I had this file in root directory of master branch:

[image]

You need replace the above element with the file you want to check.

3.The response of this api contains several commits related to this particular file, you can find the creator's information and last committer's information from the response.

**Sample response**:

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "value": [
        {
            "commitId": "xxx",
            "author": {
                "name": "xxx@outlook.com",
                "email": "xxx@outlook.com",
                "date": "2020-04-08T04:51:36Z"
            },
            "committer": {
                "name": "xxx@outlook.com",
                "email": "xxx@outlook.com",
                "date": "2020-04-08T04:51:36Z"
            },
            "comment": "Updated ConfigTrans.sln",
            "changeCounts": {
                "Add": 0,
                "Edit": 1,
                "Delete": 0
            },
            "changes": [
                {
                    "sourceServerItem": "/ConfigTrans.sln",
                    "changeType": "edit"
                }
            ],
            "url": "xxx",
            "remoteUrl": "xxx"
        },... 
        {
            "commitId": "xxx",
            "author": {
                "name": "xxx",
                "email": "xxx@outlook.com",
                "date": "2020-04-07T09:16:33Z"
            },
            "committer": {
                "name": "xxx",
                "email": "xxx@outlook.com",
                "date": "2020-04-07T09:16:33Z"
            },
            "comment": "Add project files.",
            "changeCounts": {
                "Add": 6,
                "Edit": 0,
                "Delete": 0
            },
            "changes": [
                {
                    "sourceServerItem": "/ConfigTrans.sln",
                    "changeType": "add"
                }
            ],
            "url": "xxx",
            "remoteUrl": "xxx"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can easily find the person who created the file and the person who made the last change. Hope it helps :)